# Converter cada primeira letra de cada palavra em maiúsculas

Tags: javascript

Estou com a seguinte questão:

> Escreva uma função titleize(text) que converte cada primeira letra de cada palavra em maiúsculas.
>
> ex: titleize("this IS just A tExT"); // saída correta -> (This Is Just A Text.)

Consegui deixar em maiúscula as primeiras letras de cada palavra só que não faço idéia de como conseguir **modificar o restante das letras para minúscula**.

Achei meio verbosa a minha solução se tiverem algo mais elegante fiquem a vontade.

Segue o código para que vocês visualizem o que estou fazendo:

```
function titleize(text) {

    // Convertendo primeira letra em maiuscula.
    text = text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text.charAt(i) ===" ") {

            // Convertendo letra após o ESPAÇO em maiuscula
            var charToUper = text.charAt(i+1).toUpperCase();

            // Colocando texto de antes do ESPAÇO na variável
            var sliceBegin = text.slice(0, (i+1));

            // colocando o texto de depois do ESPAÇO na variável
            var sliceEnd = text.slice(i + 2);

            // Juntando tudo
            text = sliceBegin + charToUper + sliceEnd;

        } else {

            // NAO CONSIGO PENSAR EM COMO TRANSFORMAR O RESTANTE DAS LETRAS EM MINUSCULA
        }   
    }
    return text;
}
console.log (titleize("this IS just A tExT"));
```

Percebam que não fiz nada em relação as letras centrais de cada palavra, logo elas retornam tanto maiúsculas como minúsculas :/

Minha saida atual no console:

[image: saida do console]

Como eu poderia resolver esse problema ?

Comment: "Palavra" é só o que estiver separado por espaços ou é mais complexo? Quer dizer, precisa considerar pontuação?

Comment: Vamos considerar a pontuação, creio que fica uma solução mais completa.

Comment: Ok, posso pensar nisso mais tarde. Mas se o problema imediato é só converter o resto pra minúsucula, simplesmente aplique um `toLowerCase()` em tudo antes de acertar as primeiras letras.

Comment: Funcionou @bfavaretto. Ok de qualquer forma sua solução resolve meu problema atual :) muito obrigado.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Que tal algo do tipo:

```
function titleize(text) {
    var loweredText = text.toLowerCase();
    var words = loweredText.split(" ");
    for (var a = 0; a < words.length; a++) {
        var w = words[a];

        var firstLetter = w[0];
        w = firstLetter.toUpperCase() + w.slice(1);

        words[a] = w;
    }
    return words.join(" ");
}
```

Sendo bem minimalista, pode ser escrito assim também:

```
function titleize(text) {
    var words = text.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    for (var a = 0; a < words.length; a++) {
        var w = words[a];
        words[a] = w[0].toUpperCase() + w.slice(1);
    }
    return words.join(" ");
}
```

A ideia é quebrar o texto em partes, e trabalhar cada parte em separado. Quebrando o texto pelos espaços, você não precisa se preocupar com o tratamento específico para esse caractere.

Se quiser incluir hífen ou outro caractere como separador de palavras, simplesmente quebre as palavras dentro do laço, ou crie uma função para ir montando seu array. Não esqueça de tratar a junção dos componentes depois para montar a frase de novo como string!

Comment: Renan muito obrigado, realmente você simplificou as coisas. :D

Answer (score 18):

Uma alternativa:

```js
var teste = "this IS just A tExT";
teste = teste.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(a) {
  return a.toUpperCase();
});

console.log(teste);
```

**Explicação:**

Primeiro converter a palavra toda em lower case, depois atraves de uma expressao regular obter a primeira letra e todas as letras que se seguem a um espaço em branco, substituindo esta pela respectiva em letra maiuscula.

A expressão regular:

- ?: - Faz com que a expressão entre parentesis não seja memorizada
- ^ - Faz o match à primeira letra da string
- | - Operador "ou"
- \s - Faz a um espaço em branco
- \S - Faz match a um caracter que não seja espaço em branco.

Podes ler mais a fundo sobre expressões regulares em [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Parenthesized_Substring_Matches)

Comment: Dica: é legal explicar *porquê* seu código resolve o problema. PS: escrevi este comentário na fila de análise de *Publicações de baixa qualidade*, pois respostas só com código são automaticamente postas ali para análise.

Comment: Pois, como aqui já tinha uma resposta assinalada como correcta, pensei que não haveria necessidade de entrar em grandes detalhes. Mas já adicionei uma breve explicação. Obrigado.

Comment: Show, super completa! Mesmo que seja breve, uma explicação é a diferença entre "ok" e "OOOOK" :) . . . . . . De interesse, uma discussão recente no Meta: [*Ensinar a pescar, ou dar o peixe?*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1968/201)

Comment: +1 por usar expressões regulares!

Comment: Thanks my king, very helpful =)

Answer (score 4):

Uma outra alternativa, baseada no famoso `map`:

```js
function titleize(string, separator = ' ') {
  return string
    .split(separator)
    .map((word) => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase())
    .join(separator);
}

console.log(titleize('OLÁ como vAI?'));
console.log(titleize('hELLO wORLD!'));
```

O funcionamento é simples:

Cria-se uma função que recebe dois argumentos — a string a ser formatada e um separador, que, por padrão, é um espaço em branco. Com isso:

- Separa-se a string recebida com o separador;
- Iterar sobre cada palavra (através do método [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)), capitalizando a primeira letra e transformando as demais em *lowercase*;
- Unir todas as palavras formatadas usando o separador.

Answer (score 3):

Fiz uma pequena alteração no código do Colega acima, pra ele não dar `toUpperCase()` em tudo, tipo "Maria Da Silva E Melo", agora fica Maria da Silva e Melo ....

```
function titleize(text) {
    var loweredText = text.toLowerCase();
    var words = loweredText.split(" ");
    for (var a = 0; a < words.length; a++) {
        var w = words[a];

        var firstLetter = w[0];
// aqui abaixo alterei 

        if( w.length > 2){ 
           w = firstLetter.toUpperCase() + w.slice(1);
        } else {
           w = firstLetter + w.slice(1);
        }

        words[a] = w;
    }
    return words.join(" ");
}

console.log (titleize("this IS just A tExT"));
```

Comment: Como usaria essa função diretamente num input?

Answer (score 2):

Nessa solução é bom para nomes próprios para evitar com que preposições fiquem maiúsculas.

```
function processString(text) {
        let loweredText = text.toLowerCase();
        let wordsArray = loweredText.split(" ");

        let words = wordsArray.map((word)=> {
            let firstLetter = word[0];
            if( word.length > 2){
                return firstLetter.toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
            } else {
                return firstLetter + word.slice(1);
            }
        });
        return words.join(" ");
    }
    processString('fuLanO De tAL');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function titleCase(str) {
 //pega apenas as palavras e tira todos os espaços em branco.
 return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(str) {

  //passa o primeiro caractere para maiusculo, e adiciona o todo resto minusculo
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1).toLowerCase();
 });
}

titleCase("testando a sTriNG");
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz assim:

```
var titleize = (word) => {
  var newWord = [];
  var splited = word.split(" ");

  splited.forEach( word => {
    var firstLetter = word[0].toUpperCase();
    var restLetters = word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    newWord.push(firstLetter+restLetters) 
  })

  return newWord.join(" ");
}

console.log(titleize("this IS just A tExT"));
```

Transformei a string em um array com o método `split` e depois trabalhei em cada item do array. Não é tão bonito quando usar expressão regular, mas tá valendo.

Answer (score 0):

Da para utilizar uma função dessa forma com Javascript

```
function capitalize(str) {
  if (typeof str !== 'string') {
    return '';
  }

  return `${str.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${str.substring(1).toLowerCase()}`;
}
```

ou com TypeScript

```
  export function capitalize(str: string) {
  if (typeof str !== 'string') {
    return '';
  }

  return `${str.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${str.substring(1).toLowerCase()}`;
}
```