# Regex para deixar primeira letra de nome completo maiúsculo, mesmo com caractere espeial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, front-end

Tenho a seguinte variável no $scope do Angular JS, com uma arrow function:

```
$scope.cad.nome.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w/g, l => l.toUpperCase());
```

A qual preciso formatar seu conteúdo, que é o nome completo de alguém. Está funcionando até o nome ter alguma acentuação ou ou "Ç". Ele faz as primeiras letras de cada nome ficarem maiúsculas, mas quando encontra um acento, ele faz a letra seguinte ficar maiúscula também. exemplo:

**MaríLia MendonçA**

Como alterar a regex para isso não acontecer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua pergunta te a resposta aqui: [Converter cada primeira letra de cada palavra em maiúsculas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32086/converter-cada-primeira-letra-de-cada-palavra-em-maiu%cc%81sculas).

Mas adaptei para formatar nomes, não vou entrar em detalhes.

```js
const formataNome = str => {
    return str.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)(?!da|de|do)\S/g, l => l.toUpperCase());
};

console.log(formataNome('marília mendonça'))
```

Comment: Obrigado!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Um pouco overkill.. mas soluciona o problema.

```js
let regex = /^\D/g;

let nomes = [
  "maria do carmo",
  "nome com çedilha",
  "nome com &special",
  "marilia mendonça"
];

nomes
.map(nome => {
  // Essa parte q corrige o nome individualmente.
  return nome.split(" ")
          .map(part => part.replace(regex, l => l.toUpperCase()))
          .join(" ");
})
.forEach(n => console.log(n));
```

Comment: Obrigado!!!!!!!