# CAPITALIZE A STRING DENTRO DA FUNÇÃO

Tags: javascript, capitalização

Preciso resolver um exercício e não encontro uma solução. Estou aprendendo JavaScript ainda.

```html
function capitalize(word){
    return 
}
```

preciso capitalizar a palavra inserida na variável word, mas não imagino como fazer isso, me ajudem por favor

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Converter cada primeira letra de cada palavra em maiúsculas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32086/converter-cada-primeira-letra-de-cada-palavra-em-maiu%cc%81sculas)

Comment: sim, sim, obrigada!